# Jquery mouseover and mouseout and show div at the current position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I basically wanted to show div at the current position of the mouse on mouseover. I searched most of the answers on stack exchange and came up with the solution.

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    function onmouseover (value, e)
    {
            var mouseX = e.pageX;
            var mouseY = e.pageY;
            $('.box').hide();
            $('.box').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX});
            $('.box').toggle();

    }
    function onmouseout (value) {
        $('.box').hide();

    }
    //Get the message ID
    $(document).on ({
        click: function (e) {
            if (e.target.nodeName == "A")
            {
                e.stopPropagation();
                //e.preventDefault();
            }
            else
            {
                console.log($(this).children('#msgid').text());
            }
        },
        mouseover: function (e) {
            if (e.target.nodeName == "A")
            {

                var value = ($(e.target).attr('href'));
                onmouseover(value, e);
            }
        },
        mouseout: function (e) {
            if (e.target.nodeName == "A")
            {
                var value = ($(e.target).attr('href'));
                onmouseout (value, e);  
            }
        }
    }, ".comment-item");
```

I can see the div on mouseover, but it's not at the position of the mouse.

```
<div class="box"><iframe src="#" width = "50px" height = "50px"></iframe></div>
```

This is the all solution that I have found, But it,s not working for me.

What have I missed?

Comment: Let me get the dumb question out of the way first.  You are absolute positioning the 'box' right?

Comment: Thanks Taplar that helped a lot . :).

Comment: outer div might not have breathing space to iframe. Iframe doesn't allow the mouse events to parent so add some passing to div and try it, also use mousemove event of required

Comment: Yes Taplar. But now it keeps blinking when I mouseover.

Comment: Well, you are doing a hide() on it.  Maybe you want to differentiate between a mouseenter and a mouseover.

Comment: I changed the code a lot. came out with, $(document).ready(function(e) {
 function onmouseover (value, e)
 {
   var mouseX = e.pageX;
   var mouseY = e.pageY;
   $('.box').stop().fadeIn().css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX});
   console.log(e.target.nodeName);

 }
 function onmouseout (value) {
  $('.box').stop().fadeOut();
  
 }
But still it keeps firing onmouseover. But if the div is not displayed everything is fine. I tried mouseenter too, mouseenter never gets fired.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with this problem? It will be easier to help you to solve this.

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/a3sLwajz/3/